# Spark: reduce double precision

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to concat double fields into a string field, reducing the precision (6 numbers).

eg. from 
    lat=38.04900573076923
    lon=-4.039010807692307

I want 
    location=38.049005,4.090108

Strangely, this doesn't work as expected:

```
df.withColumn("location", concat(col("lat").cast(DecimalType(6, 6)), lit(","), col("lon").cast(DecimalType(6, 6)))
```

As a result, location is always null.

Looking at DoubleType, it doesn't inherit from DecimalType so this sounds quite logical.

What is the good way to do it?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just rounding the value instead?

```
df.withColumn("location", concat(round(col("lat"), 6), lit(","), round(col("lon"), 6)))
```

You may need to cast the `round()` to a string, but it might happen inherently.